# Pass array from one controller to another. Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel-5

I'm trying to pass array from one controller to another. But I have no idea how to that.
I have my Bill Controller with array:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id,$sid)

{
$selected = array();
    if ($request->annual != 0) {
        $selected['annual'] = $request->annual;
    }
    if ($request->registration != 0) {
        $selected['registration'] = $request->registration;
    }
    if ($request->monthly != 0) {
        $selected['monthly'] = $request->monthly;
    }
    if ($request->annual != 0) {
        $selected['annual'] = $request->annual;
    }

return redirect()->route('invoice', [$sid]);

}
```

Here, I have passed $sid to another controller PdfController through route.

My Route:

```
Route::get('sid/{sid}', 'PdfController@invoice')->name('invoice');
```

PdfController:

```
class PdfController extends Controller
{

     public function invoice($sid) 
    {

        $data = $this->getData();
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $student = Student::where('id',$sid)->first();

        $view =  \View::make('layouts.bill',compact('data', 'date','student'))->render();
        $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        $pdf->loadHTML($view);
        return $pdf->stream('invoice');

    }
```

How can I pass array from my BillController to my PdfController? Can anyone help me?

Comment: pass what array, and why?

Comment: Pass array: $selected. $selected is the values got from post method. BillController saves this in database and pdfcontroller does all the printing stuff. Here, Bill controller is saving $selected and i want those selected values to be printed from my pdfcontroller.

Comment: if you saved them to the database, have your other controller just pull them from the database, or store them in the session and pull them

Comment: Yeah right, Why didn't I thought of that! BOOM!

Answer (score 0):

You can use different ways,

1. Create a cache (Cache::forever) variable and pass it.
2. Create a database temporary table with model and pass it.
3. Create a static variable and first set your variable and get again.

If you can tell which data you need to pass, we can help you much better.

Comment: Thank You @Rys for the answer i used database table. It is working fine!